# jsoncpp integration on linux

Tags: c++, cmake, jsoncpp, xubuntu

I'm trying to integrate jsoncpp to a project. My platform is a 32-bit xubuntu with gcc version 4.7.2. I tried to use the debian package, also a build from latest jsoncpp sources, both results in same issue.

I used CMake for my builds. The jsoncpp includes and library are found successfully. But when I add the includes to my CMake includes, the build of my empty brConfig class (which has only one #include  in line 51) fails with the following error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/brCore.dir/src/brConfig.cpp.o 
In file included  from /usr/include/c++/4.7/i686-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:414:0, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:40, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/include/brCore/brConfig.h:51, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/src/brConfig.cpp:25:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/i686-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:45:19: Fehler: fehlender binärer Operator vor Token »(« 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar:46:0, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/postypes.h:42, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:42, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:42, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/include/brCore/brConfig.h:51, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/src/brConfig.cpp:25: 
/usr/include/wchar.h:75:43: Fehler: fehlender binärer Operator vor Token »(« 
In file included from /usr/include/sched.h:43:0, 
from /usr/include/pthread.h:25, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/i686-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:41, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/i686-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:150, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/atomicity.h:34, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:41, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:54, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/include/brCore/brConfig.h:51, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/src/brConfig.cpp:25: 
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/sched.h:133:20: Fehler: fehlender binärer Operator vor Token »(« 
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/sched.h:171:20: Fehler: fehlender binärer Operator vor Token »(« 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar:46:0, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/postypes.h:42, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:42, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:42, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/include/brCore/brConfig.h:51, 
from /home/hellhound/Repository/binrevengine/modules/brCore/trunk/src/brConfig.cpp:25: 
/usr/include/wchar.h:104:1: Fehler: »__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_C99« bezeichnet keinen Typ /usr/include/wchar.h:107:1: Fehler: »__END_NAMESPACE_C99« bezeichnet keinen Typ /usr/include/wchar.h:135:1: Fehler: »__END_NAMESPACE_STD« bezeichnet keinen Typ /usr/include/wchar.h:149:6: Fehler: expected initializer before »__THROW« /usr/include/wchar.h:153:39: Fehler: expected initializer 
    [...]
```

It seems to me that the issue is invoked by the std::string include. 
Any idea what is going wrong?

Here is my simple class:

```
#ifndef BINREV_CONFIG_H__
#define BINREV_CONFIG_H__

#include <string>      // compile fails here if I add JSON includes to CMAKE

namespace binrev{
namespace brCore{

class CORE_LIBRARY_API brConfig
{
   public: 
     brConfig();     
     virtual ~brConfig();

};
}//ns-brCore
}//ns-binrev
#endif //BINREV_CONFIG_H__
```

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` before the jsoncpp headers?

Comment: No. This include is done in my class. The jsoncpp headers are included with cmake command INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES. Actually there is no explicit json include in my class.